# Making tuple types by picking a partial of existing object types?

Tags: typescript

The DB client we use requires array of array when executing batch update (e.g. `batchUpdate(queryStr,[[1, true], [2, false]])`) so I created 3 tuple types for that. The sequence in each sub array matters.

As shown below, each array has overlapping type (and also meaning) with one another because the update happens on the same table. My question is whether there could be a simple way to avoid defining 3 different types here. I did look up things like Map Types and Utility types but since I want an array of tuple types as the end result, it looked a bit too complicated in the current context (there are only 3 types here not a dozen)

```js
type DeleteParams = [id: number, name: string][];

type InsertParams = [
  id: number,
  name: string,
  status: boolean,
  createdAt: string,
][];

type UpdateParams = [
  id: number,
  status: boolean,
  name: string,
][];

function getUpdateList(): {
  deleteList: DeleteParams; 
  insertList: InsertParams;
  updateList: UpdateParams;
} {
  ...
}
```

If I just defined a plain object type it would have been much easier (e.g. could just use `Pick`) but that way, it will be required to convert array of object to array of tuples which is a waste of resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that meet your needs?

```js
type CommonParams = [id: number, name: string];

type DeleteParams = CommonParams[];
type InsertParams = [...CommonParams, ...[status: boolean, createdAt: string]][];
type UpdateParams = [...CommonParams, ...[status: boolean]][];

function getUpdateList(): {
  deleteList: DeleteParams;
  insertList: InsertParams;
  updateList: UpdateParams;
} {
  return {
    deleteList: [
      [1, "one"],
      [2, "two"],
    ],
    insertList: [
      [1, "one", true, Date().toString()],
      [2, "two", true, Date().toString()],
    ],
    updateList: [
      [1, "one", false],
      [2, "two", true],
    ],
  };
}
```

It uses the spread operator on types to be able to reuse `CommonParams`.

You can also create `InsertParams` from `UpdateParams` to not define `status` twice.